# Define Javascript functions from Go webassembly

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

How can we define Javascript code/functions from within Go code with Webassembly?

I want to do something similar as can be done in C with Emscripten:

```
    #include <emscripten.h>

    int main() {
      EM_ASM(
        alert('hello world!');
        throw 'all done';
      );
      return 0;
    }
```

Is there a similar function in Go to execute Javascript code?

Also in with EM_ASM() it is not possible to call defined JS functions from other places, I would like to also be able to define functions so they can be called multiple times. (as if they were just defined in a seperate js file).

Comment: its not webassembly however you can execute your go which in turn synthesizes js      https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs

Comment: Are you wanting to call JS functions from within Webassembly?

Comment: Yes I want to call JS functions from within Webassembly, I think GopherJS doesn't produce wasm but asm.js code, I'm using TinyGo as compiler.